# Error al insertar spring batch a base de datos Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, batch

Estoy tratando de insertar la información de un archivo de Excel en MySQL, estoy usando la extensión de SpringBatch Excel para leer el archivo, pero cuando intento insertar el MySQL, aparece un error, aparentemente no envía la información que compartí en mi `batch. config`

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Pagare pagare() {
        return new Pagare();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ItemProcessor<Pagare, Pagare> itemProcessor() {
        return new PagareItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        // dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pagare");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"));
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"));
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Pagare> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper() {
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Pagare> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("pagare");
        return fieldSetMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    ItemReader<Pagare> pagareReader() {
        PoiItemReader<Pagare> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("pagares.xlsx"));
        reader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    private RowMapper<Pagare> excelRowMapper() {
        return new RowMapperImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Pagare> beanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider() {
        return new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Pagare> JdbcBatchItemWriter(DataSource dataSource,
                                                  BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Pagare> sqlParameterSourceProvider) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Pagare> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(sqlParameterSourceProvider);
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql("insert into pagare(operacion,rut,contrato,tipo,analista,fechaCargaDocumento,estadoOperacion,fechaCambioEstado) values (:operacion, :rut, :contrato, :tipo, :analista, :fechaCargaDocumento, :estadoOperacion, :fechaCambioEstado)");

        return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job jobCsvMysql(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step step) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobCsvMysql").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                      ItemReader<Pagare> pagareReader, ItemWriter<Pagare> writer, ItemProcessor<Pagare, Pagare> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Pagare, Pagare>chunk(6)
                .reader(pagareReader).processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }

}
```

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into pagare(operacion,rut,contrato,tipo,analista,fechaCargaDocumento,estadoOperacion,fechaCambioEstado) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Column 'rut' cannot be null; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'rut' cannot be null

Traté de cambiar los valores de mi bd y mi modelo y tengo el mismo resultado, la razón por la que uso BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider es porque mis parámetros de la inserción son iguales a los de mi propiedad de mi modelo que dejo a continuación

```
public class Pagare {
    private String operacion;
    private String rut;
    private String contrato;
    private String tipo;
    private String analista;
    private String fechaCargaDocumento;
    private String estadoOperacion;
    private String fechaCambioEstado;




    public String getOperacion() {
        return operacion;
    }

    public void setOperacion(String operacion) {
        this.operacion = operacion;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getAnalista() {
        return analista;
    }

    public void setAnalista(String analista) {
        this.analista = analista;
    }

    public String getFechaCargaDocumento() {
        return fechaCargaDocumento;
    }

    public void setFechaCargaDocumento(String fechaCargaDocumento) {
        this.fechaCargaDocumento = fechaCargaDocumento;
    }

    public String getEstadoOperacion() {
        return estadoOperacion;
    }

    public void setEstadoOperacion(String estadoOperacion) {
        this.estadoOperacion = estadoOperacion;
    }

    public String getFechaCambioEstado() {
        return fechaCambioEstado;
    }

    public void setFechaCambioEstado(String fechaCambioEstado) {
        this.fechaCambioEstado = fechaCambioEstado;
    }

    public String getRut() {
        return rut;
    }

    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }

    public String getContrato() {
        return contrato;
    }

    public void setContrato(String contrato) {
        this.contrato = contrato;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pagare [operacion=" + operacion + ", rut=" + rut + ", contrato=" + contrato + ",tipo=" + tipo + ",analista=" + analista + ",fechaCargaDocumento=" + fechaCargaDocumento + ",estadoOperacion=" + estadoOperacion + ",fechaCambioEstado=" + fechaCambioEstado + "]";
    }
```

Mi item processor es este

```
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PagareItemProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Pagare process(Pagare pagare) throws Exception {

        LOG.info("Processing " + pagare);

        final String initCapAnalista = pagare.getAnalista().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + pagare.getAnalista().substring(1);
        final String initCapTipo = pagare.getTipo().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + pagare.getTipo().substring(1);
        Pagare transformedPagare = new Pagare();
        transformedPagare.setOperacion(pagare.getOperacion());
        transformedPagare.setAnalista(initCapAnalista);
        transformedPagare.setTipo(initCapTipo);
        return transformedPagare;


    }

    }
```

Esta es la imagen de la consola cuando lee y da el error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAE2I.png)

Comment: Lo he arreglado en mi item processor el solo tenia que iniciar una nueva instancia de mi objeto pagare y hacer un 
    transformedPagare.setOperacion(pagare.getOperacion()) asi con cada una de las propiedades de mi objeto